# Python - Check Words not in Files in Folder

Tags: python, file, find

I'm formulating a script to check if a certain word is in a path or not.

The problem I'm facing is that I can't seem to get a specific result without individual files results.

```
Example:
path = "/opt/webserver/logs/"

file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
....
...
..
file10000.txt
```

Code below:

```
#checkWordinFiles.py
import os

words = [ "Apple", "Oranges", "Starfruit" ]
path = "/opt/webserver/logs"
files = os.listdir(path)
for infile in files:
        for word in words:
                if word not in infile:
                        print word
```

The problem is the word is not in every files. This script will print out the words that aren't in the files, but I want to print the word only if it's not in any of it.

I want the script to print out those words that aren't in any of the files in the path.

Kinda like "grep Apple *" every single time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conceptual problem is that `os.listdir` produces a list of names of files in the directory; therefore, you are searching for the words within the file **name**, not the file **contents**. To fix this, you will need to use the file name to open and read the file.

The show-offy way:

```
import os

def contents(filename):
    with file(filename) as f: return f.read()

words = set(["Apple", "Oranges", "Starfruit"])
path = "/opt/webserver/logs"
filenames = os.listdir(path)
print words.difference(
    reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y), (
        # Note that the following assumes we really want to treat the file
        # as a sequence of words, and not do general substring searching.
        # For example, it will miss "apple" if the file contains "pineapples".
        set(contents(filename).split()).intersection(words)
        for filename in filenames
        # In fact, the .intersection call there is redundant, but might improve
        # performance and will probably save memory at least.
    ))
)
```

Comment: So I need to open each one, find if it exist, then flag it as found. If none found, print the word..

Comment: There is a more elegant approach: For each file, create a `set` of all the words from `words` that are found in the file. Take the union of these sets, and the difference between that union and the original word set. I'll write it up...

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with lambda, but what does reduce() do?

Comment: Basically it intersperses the operation between the elements of the sequence (here, my sequence comes from a generator expression). So `reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, ...)` (don't write it like that; there's a helper in the `operator` module that represents multiplication) gives you a product of the elements. For addition, the `sum` function is preferred; `reduce` in general is seen as, well, show-offy. :) Sometimes an initial element is required as a third parameter. As always, see the built-in documentation (`help(reduce)`) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you wanna search for a word "foo" in /path/to/file.

Do,

```
for line in open("/path/to/file"):
    if "foo" in line:
         print "hurray. you found it"
```

Modify it to work for you. You can get the name of files using os.listdir() and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you could do it:

```
for word in words:
    word_found = False
    for infile in files:
        if word in infile:
            word_found = True
            break
    if not word_found:
        print "%s not in any file" % word
```

Comment: To the person downvoting, please let me know what I did wrong or what you were expecting instead. I'd love to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

```
#checkWordinFiles.py
import os

words = [ "Apple", "Oranges", "Starfruit" ]
path = "/opt/webserver/logs"
files = os.listdir(path)

for word in words:
    for infile in files:
        if word in infile:
            break;
    else:
        print 'word - %s not found in any of the files' % (word,)
```

EDIT: I didn't pay attention to file reading login.  As @Karl mentioned, you should read all the files in the path and then search for words in the file.  You can use `os.walk()` to get the list of all files in the path including those in subdirectories.